# Pass a method as parameter to an XAML object

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working with a `CustomObject` that needs a `CustomObjectRenderer` for each platform.

I would like to pass a method as parameter to this object, from the XAML side, so I would be able to use this callback, from my renderer.

```
<control:CustomObject Callback="CallbackFunction"/>
```

The `CallbackFunction(object param)` is then declared in the **MainPage.xaml.cs** of the PCL part.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        base.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public void CallbackFunction(object param)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine((object as Element).Name);
    }
}
```

---

So, if I'm understanding well, my `CustomObject` have to be like that:

```
public CustomObject : Object
{
    public Action<object> Callback { get; set; }
}
```

But I have an error about XAML parsing.. I don't get why this error is thrown..

At the end, what I want to do, it's to call this method from the renderer, and then handle things, do actions from the MainPage.xaml.cs, from the PCL part.

```
public class CustomObjectRenderer : ObjectRenderer
{
    NativeObject nativeObject;
    CustomObject customObject;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomObject> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            customObject = e.NewElement as CustomObject;
            nativeObject = Control as NativeObject;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    // Etc etc .... 

    private void METHOD_CALLED_BY_EVENT(object o)
    {
        // This method get call by the renderer event and then, I want to call 
        // the method CallbackFunction(object); and do actions.
        customObject.Callback(o as OBJECT_PARAM);
    }
}
```

Ok, it's a bit hard for me to explain my problem to you, so if you don't understand something, let me know.

Comment: A briliant Idea. I might see some very useful applications for this method. But know this XAML instantiates objects and uses string to object converters. You might need a custom converter for this purpose.

Comment: Take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using events.

**MyView**

```
public class MyView : View
{
    public event EventHandler<string> MyEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent(string parameter)
    {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, parameter);
    }
}
```

**Page.xaml**

```
<local:MyView MyEvent="MyView_OnMyEvent"></local:MyView>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyView_OnMyEvent(object sender, string e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

**Renderer**

```
public class MyViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyView, SomeNativeView>
{
    private void METHOD_CALLED_BY_EVENT(string param)
    {
        Element.RaiseEvent(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, such a good answer ! However I would prefer by callback :/ But your solution is good to me :)

Answer (score 0):

### After lot of tried, which didn't work, I had an idea, I tried and it works as I wanted by asking my question.

---

First, create your custom object !

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainPageCallbackProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MainPageCallback), typeof(Action<object>), typeof(CustomMap), null);
    public Action<object> MainPageCallback
    {
        get { return (Action<object>)GetValue(MainPageCallbackProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainPageCallbackProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

We so use `Action` which is a container for a method/callback. But in my example, we will use `Action<object>`. Why? Because it will allows us to have an object has paramter to our callback, so we will be able to bring data back from the renderer.

Then, create a page called **MainPage.xaml** by example. In the XAML part of this new page, add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Project.CustomControl;assembly=Project"
             x:Class="Project.Page.MainPage">

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <control:CustomView MainPageCallback="{Binding MainPageCallbackAction}"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
  </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

About this XAML, two parts interest us.

- XAML 'References'

  `xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Project.CustomControl;assembly=Project"`

By these this `xmlns`, you can access your custom control.

- Content of the page

  `<ContentPage.Content>
     <control:CustomView MainPageCallback="{Binding MainPageCallbackAction}"
                         VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
   </ContentPage.Content>`

Now, we bind the `MainPageCallback` of our object to the `MainPageCallbackAction`, declared in the **C#** side.

After that, our **MainPage.xaml.cs** would seems like that:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Action<object> MainPageCallbackAction { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        base.BindingContext = this;
        MainPageCallbackAction = MainPageCallbackMethod;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainPageCallbackMethod(object param)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Welcome to the Callback :)");
            Debug.WriteLine("Emixam23 - Example");
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the last thing to look at is the `CustomViewRenderer` !

```
public class CustomViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomView, NativeView>
{
    CustomView customView;
    NativeView nativeView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            customView = e.NewElement as CustomView;
            nativeView = Control as NativeView;
            NativeView.CLicked += METHOD_CALLED_BY_EVENT;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    private void METHOD_CALLED_BY_EVENT(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        customView.MainPageCallback(ea.something.information);
    }
}
```

And then, take a look at the output, you'll be able to see the following:

- Welcome to the Callback :)
- Emixam23 - Example

---

I hope this answer is clear and helps you !